# Apps Script bring Document Properties as Global Variable

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use this global variable in my Apps Script Addon:

```
var sheet_properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
```

I've place it with other string global variables (out of functions in code.gs). It works well if I save and open the addon sidebar in my test implementation document, but if I refresh the document the Addon Menu disappears and I can't access the sidebar (only help tab is showing). The only way to bring back the menu is deleting the variable or putting inside a function, but I don't want to call getDocumentProperties in every function that use sheet_properties.

How could I proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) pattern:

```js
function someFunctionThatUsesProperties() {
  sheet_properties.setProperty('test', 'test value');
  console.log(`sheet props: ${JSON.stringify(sheet_properties)}`);
}

// ... at the end of the script file:
let sheet_properties;

function setGlobals_() {
  sheet_properties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
}

(function () { setGlobals_() })();
```

Another alternative is to use a global `props` object, and always access it through a getter function, like this:

```js
function anotherFunctionThatUsesProperties() {
  const props = getProps_();
  pros.sheet.setProperty('test', 'test value');
  console.log(`sheet props: ${JSON.stringify(props.sheet)}, user props: ${JSON.stringify(props.user)}`);
}

// ... at the end of the script file:
const props = {};

function getProps_() {
  if (Object.keys(props).length) {
    return props;
  }
  props.sheet = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  props.user = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  return props;
}
```

Comment: it's not working, the menu still does not appear with this code :(

Comment: Edited the answer. The issue with add-on menu not showing may also be caused by something else. Try re-authorizing the add-on by uninstalling it through **Extensions > Add-ons > Manage add-ons**, then install again to re-authorize.